# Dynamic constraints update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In my project there is a specific stuff I'd like to implement but for doing that I might change constraints of views dynamically. Let's say I've got a UIView instance and a UILabel one. The picture below shows how it looks like. (The picture is a little bit huge, it's all iPhone 6 you know ;P)

[image]

It's initially being like that. But when a view appeared I make calculations (to determine whether to change a container's height or not) and apply them. If the container (a grey colored view) is necessary to be decreased an app does it and finally we might get something like...

[image]

I wish it could work exactly the same I just described but... It does not. Instead, it goes like...

[image]

So the container is changed in its height but the label right below is at the same place even though there were constraints. So I wonder how to dynamically update views locations according to their updated sizes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the constraints on the label?  It it pinned to the bottom of the other view?  How are you updating the view's height?  Are you modifying the `constant` property of a height constraint?

Comment: All constraints are set by Xcode. When the main's controller's view is appeared ('viewDidAppear:' method) I call my calculation methods and there I either increase the height or decrease 'frame.size.height'. I don't do anything with constraints and this is why I'm asking here. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use constraints explicitly. The label in particular must have the constraint "top space to view" set to N points.
Then set an outlet in your view controller from the constraint "Height of view" and change that constraint to resize view height.

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func changeViewHeight(sender: AnyObject) {

    viewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
}
```

Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added an outlet for a NSLayoutConstraint, when a view is appeared I change the height for a specific view but the constant of the constraint is just the same. Could you please try to create a view and dynamically change its height with other view's constraint?

Comment: If you're using constraints, you cannot modify your view's size properties directly; only through constraints. I would suggest watching the WWDC talks introducing auto layout and 'advanced autolayout by example'. 2012, I think?

Comment: Exactly, with autolayout you change the view height modifying the constant of the relative constraint, as in my example.

Comment: Well, I've been in iOS programming for a couple months so a lot of stuff is still unknown. But anyways it works! Thank you guys!

Comment: [Here is example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-3KqjBr0ow) from Jonathan Rasmussen, even though he uses mostly programmatic auto-layout in his videos (no Storyboard/XIBs), I think this video describes pretty much how you can update constraints "dynamically" as @valfer suggested.